# Opening BBMaps from browser on BlackBerry OS 5+

Tags: web-applications, kml, blackberry-storm, blackberry-maps

I have been totally unable to open BBMaps from the BlackBerry browser from BBOS5 devices using the approach their documentation indicates. Is this functionality really broken - is the documentation really that wrong? Or am I doing something wrong?

Support for doing just this was added in BBOS 4.5 and allegedly exists through version 6. There's [an old thread about it on the BlackBerry forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Map-Links-Support/m-p/47454/highlight/true#M306); one of the sample websites in that thread does not work on the Storm 2, while the other application is down.

[Per the documentation, BBOS 5 allegedly supports both KML and the proprietary BlackBerry location markup language XLOC.](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/Open_BB_Maps_from_the_BB_Browser_898721_11.jsp)

I figured at least XLOC would work, since [version 6 allegedly retained support for XLOC and dropped KML support](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17954/Open_BB_Maps_from_the_BB_Browser_1264587_11.jsp). But nope.

I'm running 5.0.0.713 in the Storm 2 simulator and 5.0.0.1015 on a physical Storm 2.

I'm thinking the documentation is just wrong. Nothing I can do works - KML, KMZ, XLOC, dynamic generation, static files with proper MIME types, etc., etc., etc. This really shouldn't be this hard!

Here's something to ponder: if you go to a map on maps.blackberry.com in the browser... why is there no option to open it in Blackberry Maps?

As this is a professional web project, I can't publicly share the environment. I may be able to duplicate the relevant parts on my personal server, though. It's really frustrating, as we'd really like to support BlackBerry users, but we're starting to think it's not possible.

If anybody can produce a working example of doing this (for the BlackBerry Storm 2 specifically), I would be extremely grateful. If anybody can confirm that it's not possible, that would be worth something as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So! The answer lies in disregarding all of that and [using the BlackBerry Javascript API](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11849/blackberry_launch_971534_11.jsp). Just [create the address as a json object according to the spec](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11849/Address_972768_11.jsp), and call blackberry.launch.newMap like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var workAddress = {
        "address1": "1600 Pennsylvania Ave.",
        "city": "Washington",
        "country": "USA",
        "stateProvince": "DC",
        "zipPostal": "20500"
    };

    blackberry.launch.newMap({ "address": workAddress });
</script>
```

I knew there had to be a reasonable way to do it! I'm a little concerned that this seems to be little-used, but it works on the Storm 2 and allegedly works on more recent platforms, so I'm satisfied for now.

According to the spec, you can also pass lat/long and XLOC markup. I have not tested that. There doesn't seem to be any support for KML, which is a bit of a shame.

(Of course, for multiplatform web development, you'll need to add checks for the blackberry object etc.)